# closing of the PrepareStatemen in the constructor of a class

Tags: java, prepared-statement, dao

```
class StudentDAO extends AbstractDAO <Integer, Student> {

private static final String SQL_SELECT_ALL_STUDENT = "SELECT ID, FIRST_NAME, SECOND_NAME, BIRTH_DATE,ENTER_YEAR FROM STUDENT";
private static final String SQL_SELECT_STUDENT_BY_ID = "SELECT FIRST_NAME, SECOND_NAME, BIRTH_DATE,ENTER_YEAR FROM STUDENT WHERE ID=?";
private static final String SQL_SELECT_STUDENT_BY_LASTNAME ="SELECT id,FIRST_NAME,BIRTH_DATE,ENTER_YEAR FROM. STUDENT WHERE SECOND_NAME=?";
private static final String SQL_DELETE_STUDENT_BY_ID = "DELETE FROM STUDENT WHERE ID =?";
private static final String SQL_INSERT_STUDENT = "INSERT INTO STUDENT"+"(FIRST_NAME, SECOND_NAME, BIRTH_DATE, ENTER_YEAR)"+"VALUES (?,?,?,?)";
private PreparedStatement preparedStatement1;
private PreparedStatement preparedStatementSelectById;
private PreparedStatement preparedStatementfindAll;
private PreparedStatement preparedStatementDeleteStudentById;
private PreparedStatement preparedStatementInsertStudent;

public StudentDAO(Connection connection) throws DAOException, SQLException {
    super(connection);
    try {
        preparedStatementInsertStudent =connection.prepareStatement(SQL_INSERT_STUDENT);
        preparedStatement1 = connection.prepareStatement(SQL_SELECT_STUDENT_BY_LASTNAME);
        preparedStatementfindAll = connection.prepareStatement(SQL_SELECT_ALL_STUDENT);
        preparedStatementDeleteStudentById = connection.prepareStatement(SQL_DELETE_STUDENT_BY_ID);
        preparedStatementSelectById = connection.prepareStatement(SQL_SELECT_STUDENT_BY_ID);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        throw new DAOException(e);
    }

}
```

Higher a code sample, difficulties arose how to close ps in case of their use in the designer of a class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. good practice to avoid resource initialization in constructor.
2. resources like statement, create on demand and do not have it as member (field).

So I assume you will have method that uses statements. Do like :

```
public void executepreparedStatementInsertStudent (Connection connection){
       PreparedStatement preparedStatementInsertStudent   =connection.prepareStatement(SQL_INSERT_STUDENT);
    // create statement
    // execute query
    // close statement

}
public void executePreparedStatementDeleteStudentById (Connection connection){
PreparedStatement preparedStatementDeleteStudentById = connection.prepareStatement(SQL_DELETE_STUDENT_BY_ID);
    // create statement
    // execute query
    // close statement
}
```

....
and so on

**Update**

When spec says about re usage multiple times, I believe they mean case like:

```
PreparedStatement ps = connection.prepare("SQL_DELETE_STUDENT_BY_ID");

for (Student student : students) {
  ps.setInt(1, student.getId());
  ps.executeUpdate();
}

ps.close();
```

and still you close it as soon as you are done, and do not keep resource open.

Comment: but in this case in case of a repeated method call of PS it will be created again that contradicts documentation and the principle "once to create and many times to use"

Comment: if you use connection pool, it should be alright.
main goal idea that db doesn't have to compile statement again.
for example if you look apache ds 
http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-dbcp/configuration.html
look for "poolPreparedStatements"